# Can you say "einander infizieren" as an alternative to anstecken to express the idea of people infecting each other?

Tags: verb

I'm familiar with "Infizierte" being used to refer to infected person(s), so you can use it as a verb like this: "Ich hoffe die haben einander auf der Demo nicht infiziert"?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. In this context, it means the same, but note two things:

- *infizieren*, in contrast to *anstecken*, has a rather "professional" or formal sound to it. It is usually used more in scientific contexts, or when people want to sound educated.  *Anstecken* does not have such connotation and can be used in elaborate language as well as in colloquial one.  (Altough nowadays it leaks into everyday language, of course.)
- Both *infizieren* and *anstecken* are, I feel, much more often used in the reflexive construction *sich anstecken*; this expresses the aspect of involuntary contact ("getting infected"), while the transitive *jemanden/einander anstecken* has a certain volitionary ring to it.  It does not need to express "to infect someone on purpose", but does sound like that much more than the English form (since you don't have the reflexive there).

> Ich hoffe, die haben sich auf der Demo nicht infiziert.

will express the same thing a bit more naturally, unless you want to emphasize the transitive aspect.

Comment: Die Häufigkeit, mit der willentliche Ansteckungen vorkommen, spricht sehr dagegen, dass jemand den Begriff derart interpretiert.

Comment: Eh, das wollte ich eigentlich mit dem Schluss ausdrücken. Aber wenn jemand sich kritisch gegenüber so einer Demo äußert ("unverantwortlich!"), dann liegt es auch nahe, den Teilnehmern das willentliche Inkaufnehmen des Ansteckens Anderer zu unterstellen, was mit der transitiven Form besser ausgedrückt wird. Wobei ich solche Subtilitäten nicht von jedem Kritiker erwarten würde.

Comment: Jemanden absichtlich anstecken ist aber auch noch mal zu unterscheiden von eine Ansteckung bewusst in Kauf nehmen. Ersteres setzt beispielsweise voraus, dass man überhaupt ansteckend ist.